# Как сделать чтобы модуль random в python генерировал заданное кол-во чисел?

Tags: python

Как сделать чтобы модуль random в python генерировал заданное пользователем количество чисел, и записывал их в переменные(number1, number2...)?

Comment: А не лучше ли воспользоваться списком (как средством организации однородных значений), чем кучей переменных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам действительно, кровь из носу нужно сделать именно то, что вы описали - записывать значения в переменные с разными именами -  то сделать это можно примерно так :

```
n=int(input('Количество переменных ?'))
var = 'number'
for i in range(n):
    exec(var+str(i)+' = ' + str(random.random()))

print (number0,number1,number2)
>>>>  0.4762048720458498 0.5440981003615186 0.48892993316023026
```

Но "можно" не значит "нужно". Более того, такой стиль написания программ категорически не рекомендуется - такие программы невозможно поддерживать, они не самочитаемы и пр.пр.пр.
Поэтому, если вы не знаете заранее сколько однотипных переменных вам в действительности понадобиться, сделать это можно элементарно через динамический список, тем более, что на Python это проще простого:

```
number=[]
for i in range(n):
    number.append(random.random())
```

Еще один вариант - использовать массив numpy.

```
import numpy as np
number=np.random.random(n)
number
Out[31]: array([0.64145466, 0.55633192, 0.39217312])
```

Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал именно такой путь.

Comment: Для таких простых вещей используй globals вместо exec

Comment: @eri. Да, только попробуйте новичку объяснить, как globals работает и почему.  Без понятия пространства имен,  без понятия словаря и пр.

Comment: а потом неновички появляются которые не знают о контексте...

Comment: Или `[random.random() for _ in range(N)]` ... ?)